# Applied Math question: Is there a way to use the set of GPS satellite positions as a lattice?

Tags: geometry, lattice-orders, spherical-coordinates

Okay,

I am wondering if it is possible to take a satellite constellation, say the gps satellites, and use the satellites' positions (at time $t$) as points (shown below) and use them as a lattice.

[image: Satellite positions]

Some facts about the constellation:

- GPS Satellites lie in 6 planes.

  - Each plane is inclined 55 degree.
- There are between 4 and 6 satellites in each plane. (they are not evenly spaced)
- Their orbital paths are circular (i.e. $\text{eccentricity} \approx 0$).  If it helps, let's assume that that their orbits are circular.

I suppose what I am looking for is this:  Given a set of points at time $t$,  $GPS_t$ with specifications stated above, is there a mapping, $f$, that derives a lattice, $L_{GPS_t}$?

## EDIT

what i mean by lattice is a convex polytope from  $GPS_t$.

references

1. [wolfram](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/applications/astronomer/Notebooks/GPSSatellites.html)

Comment: I edited your question to include the image.

Comment: Certainly there is a way to derive the position of each satellite at a given time.  They broadcast their ephemeiris, which gives the position.  From there you can get the distance between any pair.  Is that what you mean by "derive a lattice"?

Comment: What do you mean by 'a lattice'?

Comment: you might get better answers at mathematica.stackexchange.com